# Why are the objects in setData not as array in data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 const [ data, setData ] = useState( [] );

useEffect( () => {
        axios( {
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://bouvet.guru/rekrytering_flera.php"
        } ).then( ( response ) => {
            if ( response.data.indexOf( "https://" ) !== -1 ) {
                let splittedArray = response.data.split( "Data:" );
                let dataString = splittedArray[1];

                if ( dataString.includes( "<URL kommentar>" ) ) {

                    let onlyData = dataString.substring( 16 );
                    let pairedData = onlyData.split( "https://" );
                    pairedData.splice( 0, 1 );

                    pairedData.map( ( group ) => {
                        let urls = group.split( " " )[0];
                        const comments = group.replace( urls, " " );

                        setData( {
                            item: {
                                url: "https://" + urls,
                                comment: comments
                            }
                        } );
                    } );
                } else {
                    console.log( "NOPE" );
                }
            } else {
                console.log( "We could not find any data" );
            }
        } );
    }, [] );
```

I have this code.

What I want: data = [obj1, obj2, obj3].

What I get: data = obj1, obj2, obj3.

I want the objects to be inside the data array, but at the moment, data becomes an object. So when I console.log(data) I get 3 seperate objects. I want data to be an array with these 3 seperate objects inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting data to an object. Instead set it to an array and use the spread operator `[...someArray]` to avoid direct state mutation:

```
const urls = group.split( " " )[0];
const comments = group.replace( urls, " " );
const newObj = { url: "https://" + urls , comment: comments }
setData([...data, newObj])
```

A better approach is not to set state in a loop (as your component will re-render every time you setData within the loop, rather build a newState and then set it after the loop:

```
const newArray = pairedData.map( ( group ) => {
    const urls = group.split( " " )[0];
    const comments = group.replace( urls, " " );
    return { url: "https://" + urls , comment: comments }
});
setData([...data, ...newArray])
```

Also using `map()` without using its array or every return value is an antipattern:

> Since map builds a new array, using it when you aren't using the
>   returned array is an anti-pattern; use forEach or for-of instead.
>   Signs you shouldn't be using map:
>
> A) You're not using the array it returns, and/or
>
> B) You're not returning a value from the callback.
>
> [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Hmm, now I get 3 different arrays with 1 object inside, instead of 1 array with 3 objects

Comment: make sure yoou are using `[...data, newObj]` for the first example and `[...data,...newArray]` for the second example. If you do not include the `...`s (spread operator) it will do as you said in the comment here.

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved it (the second option). And now I understand a little more about why it did that, with it updating during the loop etc. 

I will upvote your answer, Thank you once again